# How to disable sorting from some specif rows in DataTables

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I've used this [table](http://www.datatables.net/). I need my first **row** of `tbody`(which displays average number of the columns) should not be sorted, I mean that row should in top always(`below thead`) like this:
[image]. How can I do this? I search solution on google and mostly I find put that row on the `thead` or something like that. But, if I try to put that row on that place, it seems so complex to me. So, is there any way put a class on the row and disabling sortng on that classed row? like: `<tr class="average no-sort"></tr>`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/PTPdA/3/)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, in my case I solved it this way:

```
var $tr = $('#yourTable tr.no-sort'); //get the reference of row with the class no-sort
var mySpecialRow = $tr.prop('outerHTML'); //get html code of tr
$tr.remove(); //remove row of table

$('#yourTable').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function(){
        //add the row with 'prepend' method: in the first children of TBODY
        $('#yourTable tbody').prepend(mySpecialRow);

    }                   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I create the second `tbody` in my table and just move all rows I need to persist in that another `tbody` like so:

```
initComplete: function() {
    var self = this;

    var api = this.api();
    api.rows().eq(0).each(function(index) {
        var row = api.row(index);
        if (row.data()...) { // condition here
            var $row_to_persist = $(row.node());
            var $clone = $row_to_persist.clone();

            $(self).find('tbody:last').append($clone);

            $total_row.remove();
            row.remove();
            api.draw();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also looking for a solution for this. It's easy to do by modifying the dom after the table has initiated, but that breaks all of the responsive features.

Need a way to keep rows at the top of the table after sorting and filtering has been done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the row which has to remain unsorted from body of the table.
2. Include the row to be added in the footer of the table if it is the last row.